# how to lift the exception : UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
       connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='etudiant',
                             user='root',
                             password='123')
       connection.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")
       if connection.is_connected():
         db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
         print("Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on",db_Info)
except Error as e :
     print (e)
```

I have this result :
Failed getting Error information (UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b"Jeu de caract\xe8res inconnu: 'utf8mb4'", 13, 14, 'invalid continuation byte'))

Comment: Are you certain that your sql server uses the latin-1 encoding though?